# Python Pandas: How to split a column on left parenthesis and remove numbers from a column of dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Completely new to Python and Pandas. Thanks in advance for your help!

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
 In [8]: test
 Out[8]: 
      Product  Price
0      A (BC)     12
1       ABC12     34
2  CD12 (EFG)     56
```

I'm trying to remove anything after left parenthesis as well as numbers from the product names. Basically, I want:

```
    Product  Price
 0   A       12
 1   ABC     34
 2   CD      56
```

I tried using test['Product'].str.split("(")[0] and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`test['Product'] = test['Product'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)')`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) content of parenthesis to empty `string` and then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df.Product = df.Product.str.replace(r"\((.*)\)", "").str.extract("([A-Z]+)", expand=False)
print (df)
  Product  Price
0       A     12
1     ABC     34
2      CD     56
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to only remove numbers? For example if I have a product name: A bc, def12. I want to leave A bc, def but remove 12.

Comment: then need `test['Product'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)')` - very similar as another solution, only add space after `Z`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Just tried, but it removed everything after the comma as well leaving only 'A bc'. Is there a way to keep everything but the numbers? 'A bc, def'

Comment: I just figured out. Used another replace()  replace("\d", "")

Comment: exactly, `print (test['Product'].str.replace('(\d)',''))`

Comment: :) Thanks so again!